# dplyr select one_of() helper returns a warning?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have two major dataframes with 2 sets of column names I want to drop:

```
df1 <- structure(list(a = c(1, 2), b = c(3, 4), c = c(5, 6), d = c(7, 
8), e = c(9, 10)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

df2 <- structure(list(a = c(1, 2), b = c(3, 4), c = c(5, 6)), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to drop any column names in the following list: "c", "d", "e".

When I just do it with `one_of()` select helper I get a warning:

```
> tibble(a = c(1,2), b = c(3,4), c = c(5,6)) %>% select(-one_of("c","d","e"))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     3
2     2     4
Warning message:
Unknown columns: `d`, `e`
```

and 0 warning for the bigger one.

Please advise how can I filter by bank of column names without warnings?
If a column I want to ignore exists in the `one_of()` ignore it, otherwise keep it.

Comment: You can wrap the expression with `suppressWarnings` to avoid printing a warning for that one call, rather than turning off all warnings for the entire session

Comment: @camille why it produces a warning? Why it doesn't understand that I give it a pool of options and if some of them are in, please -one_of() them.

Comment: Because the expected behavior is that you're selecting a subset of columns that exist. If you're trying to select a column that doesn't exist, that's usually a mistake. In your case it's not. But the warning being printed doesn't stop your code from running. If you know it's a warning you can ignore, just ignore it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope my answer will solve your problem, I used **select_if** function instead of using select's helper function. 
If you want to know more about select_if type **?select_if** in RStudio console

```
tibble(a = c(1,2), b = c(3,4), c = c(5,6)) %>% select_if(colnames(.) %in% c("a","c","d","e"))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
options(warn=-1)
```

This will turn off warning messages globally to turn it on back you can run command like:

```
options(warn=0)
```

This is not recommended, just work around for your requirement.

To Supress warning only for this code you can use Trycatch():

```
tryCatch(
suppressWarnings( tibble(a = c(1,2), b = c(3,4), c = c(5,6)) %>%
select(-one_of("c","d","e"))  
  )
  );
```